# Open source product similar to Rational Software Architect

Tags: java, open-source, code-generation, rational-rsa

Please let me know open source product similar to rational software architect which automatically generates java base classes on completion of design. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse does a good job of generating code when used with its UML plugin.

Comment: There are many plug-ins at eclipse related to UML. Can you help me to find the most used and easy tool ?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/ :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org) and his UML [plugin](http://netbeans.org/features/uml/) very helpful ...

You will probably be interested by his reverse engineering feature :

> Designers and analysts design
> applications using the UML modeling
> language, then developers generate
> Java code from the UML model. You can
> also update the model from changes
> made in the source code
> ...
> The NetBeans UML plugin provides
> template-based code generation for
> Forward Engineering. Modify the
> FreeMaker templates included with the
> NetBeans IDE to customize how code is
> generated
> ...